# Login Component Error on React.js (codesandbox attached)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, performance, logging

I am a new programmer and I recently started following a Login Form tutorial, and I am experiencing a couple of issues with it.

**Project Overview:**

As previously described, it is a login form made with create-react-app. The objective is for the user to be able to login, if it is successful, it will log `"Logged In"` on the console. If there are errors or if its unsuccessful, it will log `"Details Do Not Match"`.

**The Problem:**

Though I followed this tutorial line-by-line, there is **an unseen error in my code** that **causes the console to log `"Details Do Not Match"`.** I am curious to see where I might have written the code incorrectly.

**Below I've attached a working Codesandbox link of my code:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/project-zi3un5

Comment: For future reference, try to avoid [linking to your project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/979052) alone, and where possible include the relevant parts of your code in the question along with the link. I _think_ that's why the question was downvoted, but I've given you an upvote to counteract it :)

Comment: I just checked your code sandbox, and unfortunately the problem still exists. To clarify, if there is an error,  it will log ```"Details Do Not Match"``` when you click the "login" button. Any idea as to why it's still doing that?

Comment: [This is what I'm seeing](https://i.ibb.co/rdFS9Wh/ezgif-4-751f575d0f.gif), maybe I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a minor typo on line 17. You were comparing `details.email` to `adminUser` instead of `adminUser.email`

It should read:

```js
if (details.email === adminUser.email && details.password === adminUser.password) {
  console.log("Logged In");
  setUser({
    name: details.name,
    email: details.email
});
```

#### Here's a fixed version: [https://codesandbox.io/s/project-forked-nvmmyn](https://codesandbox.io/s/project-forked-nvmmyn?file=/src/LoginHandler.js:184-192)

[image: demo]